# Updating JxTreeTable when model changes

Tags: java, swing, redraw, swingx, jxtreetable

I'm having trouble working out the best way to repaint a JxTreeTable when the underlying model changes.

For each node in the table I have a corresponding model object, so if a model changes I can get the Node.

Thereafter, given a Node, how do you trigger a redraw/change event on the table to force it to redraw. Clues welcome, apologies for being light on details, I don't have a much to show by way of code.

Comment: TreeTableModel is-a TreeModel, so for solving notification issues start with test your custom implementation against a plain J/X/Tree: if that behaves (aka: updates) correctly, chances are high that it does in the JXTreeTable as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
            TreeTableNode parent = node.getParent();
            modelSupport.firePathChanged(new TreePath(getPathToRoot(parent)));
```

The code is called in my model, which extends, DefaultTreeTableModel.

`node` is the AbstractMutableTreeTableNode that contains the model that changed.

Answer (score 3):

It works automatically if your model fires the correct events, similar to the standard `JTree` and `JTable`.

An example with a standard `JTree` is present in the [`Swing tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
yourJxTreeTable.getTreeTableModel.fireTableRowsUpdated(firstRow, lastRow)
```

I think it would works.

Comment: unfortunately, you think wrong ;-) a) notification _always_ is the responsibility of the model itself, never call any fireXX from outside code b) there is no method fireTableRowsUpdated in TreeTableModel (it is-a TreeModel)

Comment: Mhh, ok... 
i saw that it's a TreeTableModel on this : http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html

I already have this kind of problems and a fireXX action worked fine even if it's not a clean code.

Comment: Ok, and what can i do if my JTree is not repaint ?
Explain me :)

Comment: same procedure as always: make sure your model complies to its notification contract

Answer (score 0):

DefaultTreeTableModel contains **modelSupport** field which you can use to fire events. For your case you can use the following piece of code in your model:

```
modelSupport.fireNewRoot();
```

Answer (score 0):

updateUI() method works for me, also!

My model implements TreeTableModel and I have a TreeModelSupport object in it.

When I add/remove node, I fire modelSupport.fireChildXXX method:

```
public void insertNodeInto(MutableTreeTableNode newChild, MutableTreeTableNode parent, int index) {
    modelSupport.fireChildAdded(new TreePath(getPathToRoot(parent)),  index, newChild);
}
```

I added TreeModelListener to the modelSupport object and override treeStructureChanged method:

```
        public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
            m.notifyChanges();
        }
```

My notifyChanges method likes this:

```
public void notifyChanges()
{
    treeTable.updateUI();
}
```

That's all! :)

Answer (score -1):

simple, call to JXTreeTable.updateUI();

Comment: User code should never call a components's updateUI method